# How to get the filename of a filepicker.io picture to appear in the input field next to it

Tags: filepicker.io

I am trying to get the filename of an uploaded picture to appear in the input field next to the picker button (for filepicker.io) .  Basically I am trying to find what to put in the value field for the input tag to get the filename to appear once the picture is uploaded.  Here is the code I have:

```
<div class="row margin" id='img-row'>
<input id="filename" disabled="disabled" value="<WHAT DO I PUT HERE?>" class="input" type="text" style="width: 360px;"/>
<input name="img" data-fp-class="form-simple-action-btn filepicker_launcher" data-fp-button-text="Choose Image" data-fp-services="COMPUTER,FACEBOOK,FLICKR,INSTAGRAM,PICASA" data-fp-container="modal" data-fp-mimetypes="image/*" type="filepicker" data-fp-apikey="#################" id='campaign-img-input' value="<php echo h($_POST['img'])"/>
 </div>
```

Thank you for your help!  I haven't found any other examples like this in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to do this would be to bind a function to the onchange event of the filepicker input type. Once the upload occurs, the function will be called, and you can pull the filename out of the e.fpfile attribute.

Alternatively, it may be easier to use the `filepicker.pick` call directly given that you are interested in customizing the behavior. The widget is great for a drop-in solution in many cases, but if you're looking to customize further I'd recommend using the javascript api directly.

Comment: Could you expound on this?  Maybe with a simple coding example?  I am using the widget, so when I try to call a click function with javascript it doesn't call.